# Filtering pandas dataframe for all rows where index is consecutive +/-1

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a big dataframe and I need to create a new dataframe only with the data where one index is consecutive to the other. 
For  Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
indexer = [0,1,3,5,6,8,10,12,13,17,18,20,22,24,25,26]
df  = pd.DataFrame(range(50,66), index=indexer, columns = ['A'])
```

So the desired output in this  case is:

```
     A
0   50
1   51
5   53
6   54
12  57
13  58
17  59
18  60
24  63
25  64
26  65
```

Is there a fast way of doing it in pandas? or need to do it with some kind of loop and function over each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't shift the index, so you first need to reset it.  Then use a `loc` operation together with testing both up and down one shift.  Remember to set your index back to the original.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
>>> df.loc[(df['index'] == df['index'].shift(1) + 1) 
           | (df['index'] == df['index'].shift(-1) - 1), :].set_index('index')
        A
index    
0      50
1      51
5      53
6      54
12     57
13     58
17     59
18     60
24     63
25     64
26     65
```

Comment: great answer. Thanks!

Comment: Can also use the .diff() method and consider both forward and backward differences, see my answer. We can just use logical indexing directly on the df, so no need to reset and later restore the index.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's a faster way, using the [`.diff()` method, which exists on `Series` and `DataFrame`, but not `Int64Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html). We want all the rows where either forward difference == 1 or backward difference == -1. We use logical indexing directly, and no need to otherwise mess with the index or df.

```
ixdiff = df.index.to_series().diff
df[ixdiff(1).eq(1) | ixdiff(-1).eq(-1)]

#WAS:
#ix = df.index.to_series() # convert so we can use .diff()
#df[ (ix.diff() == 1) | (ix.diff(-1) == -1) ]

     A
0   50
1   51
5   53
6   54
12  57
13  58
17  59
18  60
24  63
25  64
26  65
```

Notes:

- thanks to @Alexander for the slight improvement
- in this case we don't need to worry about the first entry in `ix.diff()` being NaN, or the last entry in `ix.diff(-1)`, since at least one of the forward- and backward- diffs will match, when consecutive. So we don't need to `.fillna(...)` as we normally would when using `diff(...)`.

Comment: My, my, this is an old post.  Yes, this is a better answer. It also can arguably be improved by adding the `diff` function to your new series:  `diff = df.index.to_series().diff`, then the boolean mask `df[diff(1).eq(1) | diff(-1).eq(-1)]`.

Comment: @Alexander: hey that's a pretty awesome suggestion, attach `diff()` directly onto the index. I always thought it was severely deficient that the index, of all things, didn't have `diff()`, cos it need its it... wonder what other Series methods we might also want to attach.